# The herokuapp jsonpath site is down

Tags: heroku

Loading https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ is returning this:

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
> served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
> You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: "Extra text to get title accepted"—please _do not_ do this. If your title needs to be improved, _improve it_. Adding garbage text just creates more work for the rest of us to clean up.

Comment: And please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. Some random site being down is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

You application might be using free Heroku plan. However, heroku has shut down their free services from November 28, 2022. You should host the website to some other hosting services.